Adding a smoothing capacitor to a bridge rectifier. Will this also add to the overall load seen at wall?
I am adding a smoothing capacitor to a bridge rectifier to run a DC motor.
The motor's load is rated at 10 amps. (100V, 1000W)
My question is, does adding a capacitor then increase the load to more than those 10 amps as it "charges"?

The reason i ask is the AC power is coming from a Variac rated for 10 amps, so if the load does increase then it will more than likely trip.

Capacitors are not rated in amps. Where is this number coming from?

You are right, sorry. The current rating i gave is the draw of the motor (10 amps)

What is the reason for adding the capacitor? There will be more stress in the rectifier.

The reason is to smooth the DC voltage coming from the rectifier which isn't clean DC but rather sinusoidal (as far as I'm aware).

What is the goal in smooth the DC voltage?

The goal is to have the DC motor running more efficient and thereby drawing less current. (I only have a 10 amp variac,the motor will sometimes draw up to 20 amps short term when more torque is applied)

The capacitor will cause the DC voltage to increase, but even if you reduce the Variac output voltage to keep the average motor voltage at 100Vdc and average current at 10A, the RMS  Variac current will go above 10A due to the high peak current that charges the capacitor at the peaks of the sinewave.  The RMS value can approach 160% of the average value if the capacitor is large enough to produce a small ripple voltage on the DC.
This means the Variac should be rated for about 16A to generate a full-wave bridge, filtered DC output of 10A.

This makes sense, thank you.

The average current will remain essentially the same, but the current waveform will become highly distorted — instead of a sine wave, you'll see tall narrow spikes of current drawn at the peaks of the voltage waveform (i.e., current flows only when the line voltage exceeds the capacitor voltage). Your Variac probably won't like that very much.
Neither will the power company. You're turning your motor into a load that has a low power factor, which means that the utility will experience higher losses while delivering power to you. They really hate that, and if you do enough of it, they'll come after you and charge you for it.

I think, if the capacitor is big enough, the effective motor DC voltage will rise and so will the motor speed and the energy consumption. If it is not big enough, it might explode anyway by this AC current load :)

Low* power factor? || I mean, the power company doesn't care about a load here or there, nor is there any policing of power factor anywhere, AFAIK. Some customers/jurisdictions may incur higher metering rates for low PF, or the ampacity is simply reduced (which affects the variac proportionately). || Note that PF is already low, because the motor is not a resistor load, but a Thevenin equivalent, rotor resistance + bEMF. Once up to speed, current will naturally be pulsating. (Assuming normal PMDC motor.) The capacitor just acts to smooth torque, at expense of even narrower pulsing.

"The average current will remain essentially the same"
good to know.
"but the current waveform will become highly distorted — instead of a sine wave, you'll see tall narrow spikes"
i'm hoping to not have a sine wave but rather have it as close to flat as possible.
"Neither will the power company"
I know very little about these effects?  You're saying this could affect the power grid?

@TimWilliams: thanks, fixed.

@Jimanee_Jeebus: The current on the output side of the rectifier will be smoother, but the current on the input side will be highly distorted.
